# Can't load facebook identity in ASP.NET using Owin

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have problem with loading Facebook identity. The page is redirect to facebook properly, but when I get back to my site, I can't read identity from Owin.

Here is my **Startup.Auth.cs**

```
var cookieOptions = new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
    LoginPath = new PathString("/default.aspx")
};

app.UseCookieAuthentication(cookieOptions);
app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(cookieOptions.AuthenticationType);
var facebookAuthenticationOptions = new FacebookAuthenticationOptions()
{
    AppId = ExternalConnections.Where(o => o.Name == "Facebook" && o.Exist && o.SiteId == site.Key).First() != null ? ExternalConnections.Where(o => o.Name == "Facebook" && o.Exist && o.SiteId == site.Key).First().AppId : string.Empty,
    AppSecret = ExternalConnections.Where(o => o.Name == "Facebook" && o.Exist && o.SiteId == site.Key).First() != null ? ExternalConnections.Where(o => o.Name == "Facebook" && o.Exist && o.SiteId == site.Key).First().AppSecretKey : string.Empty,
    SignInAsAuthenticationType = app.GetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(),
    CallbackPath = new PathString("/Default.aspx/")
};

facebookAuthenticationOptions.Provider = new FacebookAuthenticationProvider
{
    OnAuthenticated = async context =>
    {
        context.Identity.AddClaim(new System.Security.Claims.Claim("FacebookAccessToken", context.AccessToken));
        foreach (var claim in context.User)
        {
            var claimType = string.Format("urn:facebook:{0}", claim.Key);
            string claimValue = claim.Value.ToString();
            if (!context.Identity.HasClaim(claimType, claimValue))
                context.Identity.AddClaim(new System.Security.Claims.Claim(claimType, claimValue, "XmlSchemaString", "Facebook"));
        }
    }
};

facebookAuthenticationOptions.Scope.Add("email");
facebookAuthenticationOptions.Scope.Add("public_profile");

app2.UseFacebookAuthentication(facebookAuthenticationOptions);
```

And my **PageBase.cs** to handle login:

```
var ctx = Context.GetOwinContext();
var user = ctx != null ? ctx.Authentication.User : new ClaimsPrincipal();
if (user != null && user.Identities.Count() > 0 && user.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
    var claimsPrincipal = new ClaimsPrincipal(user.Identity);
    Thread.CurrentPrincipal = claimsPrincipal;
    var identity = (ClaimsPrincipal)Thread.CurrentPrincipal;

    if (identity.Claims.Count() > 0)
    {
        switch (identity.Claims.First().OriginalIssuer)
        {
            case "Facebook":

                if (!featureExternalLoginFacebook) { break; }

                id = identity.Claims.Where(c => c.Type == "urn:facebook:id").Select(c => c.Value).SingleOrDefault();
                name = identity.Claims.Where(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.Name).Select(c => c.Value).SingleOrDefault();
                accessToken = identity.Claims.Where(c => c.Type == "FacebookAccessToken").Select(c => c.Value).SingleOrDefault();

                var url = string.Format("https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/{0}?fields=email,first_name,last_name&access_token={1}", id, accessToken);

                var req = WebRequest.Create(url);
                req.Method = "GET";
                req.ContentType = "application/json";

                using (var res = new StreamReader(req.GetResponse().GetResponseStream()))
                {
                    dynamic result = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(res.ReadToEnd());

                    if (result.id != null && result.id == id)
                    {
                        email = result.email != null ? result.email : string.Empty;
                        firstName = result.first_name != null ? result.first_name : string.Empty;
                        lastName = result.last_name != null ? result.last_name : string.Empty;
                    }
                }

                break;
        }

        externalApp = identity.Claims.First().OriginalIssuer;

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(id) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(email))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

In user.Identities, I had IsAuthenticated as true. Now I have always false, and I don't have identity.Claims for Facebook.

How I can get Facebook user information about logged user, resp. how I can get facebook identity?

Answer (score 0):

Facebook has recently deprecated some of their OAuth endpoints. If you are using the NuGet package `Microsoft.Owin.Security.Facebook` 3.0.1, you'll need to update to the most recent version (which will also update several related packages).

- Right click on project
- Select "Manage NuGet Packages"
- Select "Installed"
- Search for "Facebook" or find the package from the list
- Select "Microsoft.Owin.Security.Facebook" and click "Update"

Reference: https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetKatana/issues/38